# fortrabbit showing 404 on live but works on dev

Tags: hover, fortrabbit

I have an issue on fortrabbit which I can't figure out on my own, and google is not of much help either.

I have this website which works fine on the temp domain that fortrabbit gives upon creating the app: [App on Dev](http://blackflame.eu2.frbit.net/). Now I have an actual domain for this which is: [App on Live](http://www.blackflame.digital), but it shows a 404 page for some reason. The app is configured in fortrabbit to point to the 'public' folder and overall has the same setup as the Dev app, but I still can't figure out why it shows a 404 page.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds as if everything is configured correctly. To further digg into the problem: A) ensure that a "custom domain" is added to the app in the fortrabbit Dashboard — test with a local host file modification B) ensure that the custom domain is pointed to the App URL as a CNAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix for this. The domain in fortrabbit dashboard had to be set to "www.blackflame.digital", it was set to "blackflame.digital" before, so just had to add the "www" at the beginning.